# How to sort a 2 dimention array of integers? In python 3 with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**How can i sort an array like this:** `arr=[[2,1,1,2,3,3],[1,1,2,3,2,2],[1,2,1,3,2,2]]`
**Into**: `sorted_arr=[[1,1,2,3,2,2],[1,2,1,3,2,2],[2,1,1,2,3,3]]`

thats not part of my code its just an example of what i need. I have an array with a lot of arrays and integers on it, and the integers are 1,2,3 i want to sort it, for example, one array is 111111111 and is in the middle of the main array, i want it at the beginning

The logic is, that in my real code i have 2 arrays and i compare them, so i have a nested loop, and to make it faster, if a very close elemnts are at the beggining it will speed a lot my code, so thats why i want to sort it, The array has a lot of arrays with splitted integers into it, so i want to sort that arrays like the integer would be 1

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! It would be great if you could post some code that you have written to solve this problem. It will help us to point out the mistakes. For more info on how to task a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: numpy has a `sort` function

Comment: thats not part of my code its just an example of what i need. I have an array with a lot of arrays and integers on it, and the integers are 1,2,3 i want to sort it, for example, one array is 111111111 and is in the middle of the main array, i want it at the beginning

Comment: @PaulH yeah, i tried and kt didnt work

Comment: along which axis?

Comment: @diegow98 Could you please edit your question and post the details as you mentioned in one of your comments? From the question, the sorting criterion is unclear.

Comment: I tried with -1,0,1

Comment: this all information that belongs in the question

Comment: in the first row of the sorted array, why is 3 before two 2s?

Comment: Because i want to sort the array not the elements inside

Comment: you're not explaining the logic behind your output clearly

Comment: The logic is, that in my real code i have 2 arrays and i compare them, so i have a nested loop, and to make it faster, if a very close elemnts are at the beggining it will speed a lot my code, so thats why i want to sort it, The array has a lot of arrays with splitted integers into it, so i want to sort that arrays like the integer would be 1

Comment: @diegow98 Please post this entire comment as part of your question. The question still lacks details.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(arr)
```

works for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: @diegow98 Well, what are you waiting for, then?

Comment: Oh, i thought you said the sort func of numpy, i will try it

Comment: I tried and that function doesnt work for more than 1 dimention array

Comment: @diegow98 Could you indicate why `np.sort` didn't work for you? For your sample input, it seems to be giving the expected output. `array([list([1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2]), list([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2]), list([2, 1, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)`.

Comment: I tried and it changed the values of the integers or the order inside the arrays that contains the integers. I tried with all axis and order method of np.sort

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you want to sort the rows according to the columns by interpreting the columns as the keys of primary-order, secondary-order, etc. If that is the case, `numpy.lexsort` can do a good job.

Try this code

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[2,1,1,2,3,3],
                [1,1,2,3,2,2],
                [1,2,1,3,2,2]])
argsorted = np.lexsort(arr.transpose()[::-1])
print(arr[argsorted])
```

you can easily transform `arr[argsorted]` to list by `list(arr[argsorted])`